# How do I transform this UML class diagram into to a data table?

Tags: database-design, uml, diagram, class-diagram

How do I transform this UML  class diagram into to a data table?

[image]

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What definitions? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: As Christophe mentioned the class names are in the wrong compartment. They need to be on top!

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal rule to transform a class diagram into a database schema. There are a set of techniques that can be used, with choices to be made case by case.

In absence of inheritance, and assuming that there is a graphical issue in your diagram and `Point` and `MultiPoint` are
class names, and that you’re targeting an RDBMS, one simple approach could be:

- create a table for each class
- for each table find the unique identifier among the attributes (sometimes adorned with `{id}`). In absence of any unique identifier, add one.
- the unique identifier will be primary key of the table.
- the one to many composition could be represented with a foreign key in the table on the “many” side. So you’d add a column in `MultiPoint`, that would reference a primary key of `Point`.  You should then add an on-delete-cascade constraint, to ensure that the deletion of a  multipoint, causes all the related points to be deleted
  as well.
- in each table, add the  attributes as columns (strings, numbers, …). If an attribute would be of a class type, you’d need to handle it as an association with that class.